# Concept question for vector space $S\subset V$ and its dual

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S\subset V$ both be finite dimension vector space over $\Bbb{R}$.If we assume $\dim(S) <\dim V <\infty$.We know that $\dim S = \dim S^*$ (where $S^*$ is the algebra dual of $S$ ) and same result holds for $V$.

There is a question that confuse me here is we know $S\subset V$ implies $V^*\subset S^*$(using the dual map of inclusion),hence this implies $\dim V^*\le \dim S^* <\dim V$ contracdiction.

What's wrong with the above argument?

Comment: The dual map of the inclusion is not an inclusion, it's a surjection. That is, the inclusion $S\hookrightarrow V$ induces a map $V^*\to S^*$, you are correct in that, but if you check what that map is you will see that it is not an injection, but instead is a surjection.

Comment: Oh thank you,We need to check that $S$ has dense image on $V$ (for example in functional analysis) then it's injection correct? @Arturo Magidin

Comment: The dual of a monomorphism (in this case, an injection) is an epimorphism (dense image). The dual of an epimorphism (in this case, linear map with dense image) is a monomorphism (injective linear map).

Comment: In fact we have a more precise statement about the dual vector space, Let $S\subset V$ then for the dual map we have $V^*\to S^*$ since it needs not to be injective,if we mod the kernel then by first isomorphism theorem we have $(V^*)/S^\perp \cong i^*(V^*)$ By Hahn-Banach theorem dual map is surjective hence $S^* \cong (V^*)/S^\perp$

Comment: Recall that  $S^\perp$ is trival if and only if $S$ has dense image in $V$ hence this coinside with what we said above.